# click button to switch div positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

**Brief Explanation:** I have `div1` and `div2` onside a `<div>`. On right click i open context menu which has a button **switch**.

On clicking this button i want div1 and div2 to switch positions,

attached pic for your reference:
[image]

here is my code:

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", "div", function(event) {

  // alert("right clicked");
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.clickedElement = $(this);
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this.clickedElement).addClass('selecteddiv');
  $(".custom-menu4").show();

  $(".custom-menu4 li").unbind().click(function() {
    switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
      case "second":
        $(".custom-menu4").hide();
        $(".selecteddiv").removeClass('selecteddiv');
        break;
      case "first":
        alert("clicked switch");
        break;
    }
  })
  // alert("add");
});
```

```css
.selecteddiv {
  border: 1px solid rgb(180, 13, 172);
}

.custom-menu4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="click" style="padding: 20px">
  <div class="switch">Hello</div>
  <div class="switch">World</div>
</div>

<ul class='custom-menu4'>
  <li data-action="first">Switch</li>
  <li data-action="second">Cancel</li>
</ul>
```

link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzvLdgrb/65/)

> On clicking the switch button, the div1 should switch position with div2, **i mean in whatever positions they are, they should switch.**

Please help.

Comment: no working on ncomputing server :)

Comment: @lois6b pretty sure you can style Win7 like that with a theme. It might even be built in. Looks like a Win7 toolbar to me.

Comment: on your fiddle while clicking on the first div it switches both. whats exactly your problem ?

Comment: i want them to switch by clicking on "switch" button option  which open by right clicking the context menu

Comment: @JessicaStorm unbind() is deprecated in jQuery, you should be using off() (and on() as its opposite) - see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) - it was replaced way back in jQuery 1.7

Comment: alright, noted. Thanks for the info @ADyson

Comment: can you please update my fiddle, will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.click').find('.switch').eq(0).appendTo($('.click'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ohw25Ltf/

Comment: Please check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ohw25Ltf/7/ , right click and click switch, the right one should switch to left but it goes down rather, whats wrong in there, please help

Comment: you added a row, so your new code should be: `$('.click .row').find('.switch').eq(0).appendTo($('.click .row'));`  http://jsfiddle.net/ercanpeker/ju2h07yb/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by selecting the second element and prepending it to the div with class "click" so it becames the first.

```js
$("li:contains('Switch')").click(function() {

  $('div.switch:last').prependTo('.click');

})
```

```css
.selecteddiv {
  border: 1px solid rgb(180, 13, 172);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="click" style="padding: 20px">
  <div class="switch">Hello</div>
  <div class="switch">World</div>
</div>

<ul class='custom-menu4'>
  <li data-action="first">Switch</li>
  <li data-action="second">Cancel</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please update as per my fiddle, on right click it opens a menu and then clicking on switch should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to select the first switchable element, and move it after the other one. Demo:

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", "div", function(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.selecteddiv').removeClass("selecteddiv");
  $(this).addClass('selecteddiv');
  $(".custom-menu4").show();

  $(".custom-menu4 li").off().click(function() {
    switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
      case "second":
        $(".custom-menu4").hide();
        $(".selecteddiv").removeClass('selecteddiv');
        break;
      case "first":
        /***** This is the important bit, to do the switching ****/
        var $div = $('.switch').first();
        $div.next('.switch').after($div);
        break;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.selecteddiv {
  border: 1px solid rgb(180, 13, 172);
}

.custom-menu4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="click" style="padding: 20px">
  <div class="switch">Hello</div>
  <div class="switch">World</div>
</div>

<ul class='custom-menu4'>
  <li data-action="first">Switch</li>
  <li data-action="second">Cancel</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And what do we click on here?

Comment: @Gerard you right-click on the main area to show the context menu, and then click on the "switch" button. Just as is described in the question, and already operational in the original code. All I did was add the code to actually do the switching.

Comment: Cheers, got it.

Answer (score 2):

I simplified this a lot

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu","div", function(event) {
      
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".custom-menu4").show();
})

$('#btn-cancel').click(function (evt) {
  $(".custom-menu4").hide();
});

$('#btn-switch').click(function (evt) {
  var $div = $('#top-divs div').first();
  $('#top-divs').append($div);
});
```

```css
 .selecteddiv {
    border: 1px solid rgb(180, 13, 172);
  }
  
  .custom-menu4 {
    display: none;
    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-divs" style="padding: 20px">
  <div class="switch">Hello</div> 
  <div class="switch">World</div>
</div>

<ul class='custom-menu4'>
    <li id="btn-switch" data-action="first">Switch</li>
    <li id="btn-cancel" data-action="second">Cancel</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` with [`order`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/) and keep the DOM elements in their original location.
With this technique, you could manipulate the ordering of multiple elements quite easily only by changing their `order`.

```js
$(".switch-btn").click(function() {
  $('.switch').toggleClass('high-order');
})
```

```css
.click {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.click > div {
  order: 1
}

.click > div.high-order {
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="click">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div class="switch">World</div>
</div>

<button class="switch-btn">Switch</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in JavaScript:

```
$(".custom-menu4 li").unbind().click(function() {
switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
  case "second":
    $(".custom-menu4").hide();
    $(".selecteddiv").removeClass('selecteddiv');
    break;
  case "first":
    alert("clicked switch");
    var selected = $("div.selecteddiv").html();
    var unselected = $("div").not(".selecteddiv").html();
    $("div.selecteddiv").html(unselected);
    $("div").not(".selecteddiv").html(selected);
    $(".selecteddiv").removeClass("selecteddiv");
    break;
}
})
```

Comment: why do you need an ID? They already have a class in common, and it's easy to know which one is current first.

Comment: can you please update in fiddle so i can run and test, will be a better solution if this can be achieved without an id

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, was in development mode (easy to edit stuff) will fix.

Comment: @ADyson Fixed now, any better?

Comment: @JackBashford makes more sense. Although there's a less verbose way to do it - see my answer :-)

Comment: @ADyson Yes, that's a good answer, and I admit I don't know what verbose means yet. Still, +1 from me for a simpler code

Comment: @JackBashford https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verbose :-) . In the context of code, if something's verbose it just means it used more code than was actually necessary, and possibly by doing so made the code harder to understand and maintain .

Comment: @ADyson So verbose code is the opposite of golfed code

Comment: @JackBashford more or less. Although code golf can encourage extreme versions of shortening the code which can lead to equal, if not, greater problems of comprehension and maintainability. It depends what your goal is, but certainly to create good quality future-proof, supportable software, you want to get the simplest, shortest implementation you can which can still be readily understood by someone who isn't intimately familiar with the codebase already.